# Maven Release: Local Modifications to .java files

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to build a project on TeamCity using Maven. More specifically, I am trying to perform a release using the Maven release plugin with the goal release:prepare release:perform.

When I run this (I am using Git), I keep getting the following errors (I changed names of files for privacy reasons.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4:prepare (default-cli) on project x: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications : 
[.classpath:modified]
[.gitignore:modified]
[.project:modified]
[log/test.log:modified]
[pom.xml:modified]
[src/main/java/com/*/File1.java:modified]
[src/main/java/com/*/File2.java:modified]
[src/main/java/com/*/File3.java:modified]
[src/main/java/com/*/File4.java:modified]
[test.txt:modified]
```

I have looked into  < checkModificationExclude > but I am afraid to exclude modifications made to the .java files.

Comment: Have you checkout on command line yourself to do a `git status`?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like line-endings mismatch. Check git settings on the build agent